# Issues with Opacity effect in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, icons, opacity, shadow

What is the alternate for opacity in canvas? I have used globalAlpha, but the results are not as expected. You can see the edges are blurred out and can see some lines at the sides of the shadow.

You can have a look at image here: http://flattyshadow.com/issue/fs-paper-plane.png

Comment: What canvas-related code are you using to generate your image and how would you prefer it to look? FWIW, Canvas has 3 ways of making semi-transparent pixels (==opacity): (1) globalAlpha, (2) fillStyle with rgbA, (3) putImageData.

Comment: HI markE, I have shared a link here of my code, I have even attached the expected results.
http://jsfiddle.net/bdeepakreddy/3yu3mrmf/

Comment: In canvas, each new drawing is cumulative (unless you erase the canvas). So repeatedly redrawing your airplane with 1px x,y offsets will increase opacity with each new draw. Instead, create a path for your desired shadow and then draw that path with reduced opacity (reduced globalAlpha).

Comment: That's a great idea.. Thanks a lot markE.. Wish I could vote this..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [fillStyle](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp) property of the canvas context using [rgba](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/) function.

Comment: I did it, still it does not work as opacity. The results generated by using globalAlpha and rgba is same.